aws scheduler get-schedule returning unusual ScheduleExpression
I'm using AWS CloudShell to retrieve the configuration of my AWS EventBridge Schedule but this is returning an unusual ScheduleExpression causing problems downstream.
Commands I'm running in AWS CloudShell:
TARGET=$(aws scheduler get-schedule --name MY-SCHEDULE-NAME)  
echo $TARGET

This returns
{
  "ActionAfterCompletion": "NONE",
  "Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:eu-west-1:AWS-ID:schedule/default/MY-SCHEDULE-NAME",
  "CreationDate": "2024-11-21T17:12:01.720000+00:00",
  "Description": "MY-SCHEDULE-NAME",
  "FlexibleTimeWindow": {
    "Mode": "OFF"
  },
  "GroupName": "default",
  "LastModificationDate": "2024-11-21T17:12:01.720000+00:00",
  "Name": "MY-SCHEDULE-NAME",
  "ScheduleExpression": "cron(00 05 ? new_target.json task-def.json 1 *)",
  "ScheduleExpressionTimezone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
  "State": "ENABLED",
  "Target": {
    "Arn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:AWS-ID:cluster/MY-CLUSTER",
    "EcsParameters": {
      "EnableECSManagedTags": false,
      "EnableExecuteCommand": false,
      "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
      "NetworkConfiguration": {
        "awsvpcConfiguration": {
          "AssignPublicIp": "DISABLED",
          "SecurityGroups": [
            "sg-123"
          ],
          "Subnets": [
            "subnet-123",
            "subnet-123",
            "subnet-123"
          ]
        }
      },
      "PlatformVersion": "LATEST",
      "PropagateTags": "TASK_DEFINITION",
      "ReferenceId": "MY-TASK-DEFINITION",
      "TaskCount": 1,
      "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:AWS-ID:task-definition/MY-TASK-DEFINITION-td:1"
    },
    "Input": "{\"containerOverrides\":[{\"environment\":[{\"name\":\"refresh_type\",\"value\":\"weekly\"}],\"name\":\"MY-TASK-DEFINITION\"}]}",
    "RetryPolicy": {
      "MaximumEventAgeInSeconds": 86400,
      "MaximumRetryAttempts": 185
    },
    "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ID:role/MY-SCHEDULE-NAME-schedule-exec-role"
  }
}

As you can see, the ScheduleExpression is "cron(00 05 ? new_target.json task-def.json 1 *)". However, in the AWS Console, the Schedule is 00 05 ? * 1 *. I have no idea where the new_target.json task-def.json is coming from. I've tried editing the Schedule in Terraform and in the UI but no change in the response from AWS CloudShell. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?
Edit:
It seems that the first * is causing this. When I edit the cron to 00 06 1 1 ? * it works as expected. However, when I change it to 00 06 1 * ? * it returns new_target.json task-def.json.

That looks like a bug in the AWS API. You should report it to Amazon.

AWS CloudShell or the EventBridge API might not correctly serialize or return these fields in the expected format especially for special characters. a bug that has nothing with your configuration.
